# Visual Studios unable to debug web projects

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

A while ago I had a hard drive failure and since then all my projects that used to work no longer run. They compile file; but once I go to debug on my dev environment I get the error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I've reinstalled IIS, MVC4, VS2012.

I can run Xamarin projects, and any non-web based projects.

Full Stack Trace Below:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/sites/Solution/Project/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\sites\Project\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\sites\Project\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35


Stack Trace:


[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +57
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +285
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9950728
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +456

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237
```

Comment: BadImageFormatException happens if you run a 64-bit executable and it tries to load a 32-bit DLL, or vice-versa.  What did you do after the hard drive failure?  Is this a complete system reinstall?  If you tried to recover the drive, then perhaps you have a corrupted DLL?

Comment: We recovered the drive and copied the contents onto a new one.

Comment: That makes me wary that files might be damaged.  Perhaps reinstalling .NET would help?  Or comparing the DLL to the identical DLL on another computer?  Or perhaps forcing ngen to re-run?  Ultimately: I suspect you have a corrupted file system and you may find such issues intermittently when moving forward.

Comment: I've attempted to find the System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll and haven't found it; could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Open up a command prompt and do "dir/s c:\windows\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment*.*" There will be several versions: 32-bit, 64-bit, and MSIL version.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but the easiest solution is going to be just creating a new project and then copying the guts of your borked project into that. It shouldn't actually be that arduous. You'll just need reinstall any Nuget packages your project depends on an update the Web.config appropriately to match your borked project where appropriate.

Comment: It's not just a couple of projects that don't work, it's all old and new (web based)projects that are getting this error.

Comment: @MobyDisk You're #1, found the dll in the GAC_MSIL folder and replaced it with one from another source. And its working. Thank you!